# How to calculate DAU/MAU using Application Insights Analytics?

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

Assuming I have a definition of a user I can calculate sum of all daily users and all monthly users.

```
customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where <condition>
| summarize by <user>, bin(timestamp, 1d)
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| summarize DAU=sum(count_)

customEvents
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where <condition>
| summarize by <user>
| MAU=30*count
```

The question is how to calculate DAU/MAU? Some join magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

There is a much easier way to [calculate usage metrics](http://4pp1n51ght5.com/2017/08/23/using-azure-log-analytics-to-calculate-user-engagement-metrics) now - "evaluate activity_engagement":

```
union *
| where timestamp > ago(90d)
| evaluate activity_engagement(user_Id, timestamp, 1d, 28d)
| project timestamp, Dau_Mau=activity_ratio*100 
| render timechart
```

### -------

The DAU is really stright forward in Analytics - just use a dcount.

The tricky part of course is calculating the 28-day rolling MAU.

I wrote a post detailing exactly how to calculate [stickiness in app analytics](https://4pp1n51ght5.com/2017/02/08/calculating-stickiness-using-appinsights-analytics) a few weeks back - The trick is that you have to use hll() and hll_merge() to calculate the intermediate dcount results for each day, and then merge them together.

The end result looks like this:

```
let start=ago(60d);
let period=1d;
let RollingDcount = (rolling:timespan)
{
pageViews
| where timestamp > start
| summarize hll(user_Id) by bin(timestamp, period)
| extend periodKey = range(bin(timestamp, period), timestamp+rolling, period)
| mvexpand periodKey
| summarize rollingUsers = dcount_hll(hll_merge(hll_user_Id)) by todatetime(periodKey)
};
RollingDcount(28d)
| join RollingDcount(0d) on periodKey
| where periodKey < now() and periodKey > start + 28d
| project Stickiness = rollingUsers1 *1.0/rollingUsers, periodKey
| render timechart
```

Comment: Rolling stickiness! Will give it a try on Monday =)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this query does it:

```
let query = customEvents
| where timestamp > datetime("2017-02-01T00:00:00Z") and timestamp < datetime("2017-03-01T00:00:00Z") 
| where **<optional condition>**;
let DAU = query
| summarize by **<user>**, bin(timestamp, 1d)
| summarize count() by bin(timestamp, 1d)
| summarize DAU=sum(count_), _id=1;
let MAU = query
| summarize by **<user>**
| summarize MAU=count(), _id=1;
DAU | join (MAU) on _id
| project ["DAU/MAU"] = todouble(DAU)/30/MAU*100, ["Sum DAU"] = DAU, ["MAU"] = MAU
```

Any suggestions how to calculate it per last few months?

Answer (score 0):

Zaki, your queries calculate a point in time MAU/DAU. If you need a rolling MAU you can use the HLL approach suggested by Asaf. Or the following which is my preferred rolling MAU which is using make-series and fir(). You can play with it hands on [using this link](https://analytics.applicationinsights.io/demo?q=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3VTTW%2FbMAy951cQudTG8mF3wFasU4Gu24AdBgxDellRBIxNJ1plyZNkuy7640fZrZOtKRBElkg%2BPpKPyyV8NRYQrFFK6i18v7yGlqCVSkGL2oM3kJmaP4xWHfidcQS1I%2Bug3bFpR9kd5WBqD%2BhBEbrgmRFIzahb2ZCGHLsFrHYEnrKdln9qgg0p0wIq%2FnfQmTqksSgZ27NfZqUnKzG8ou4YtiEFpgDSW9xSSUyndoFu8C6lXmPmZSN9Bw2qmhYTRZ6dcy9LEnyagjlEOXoKL9Fpkr6fJ2%2FnSbpKkg%2F971ccn%2FdRrWT3VrxL8uHuPFr%2FjBPO%2BeAxWKVmopxTpE%2FuoTXrjdRu7c0aNarugcTp2WAsTcOk164u14VUHCm8cRkqtJFFvSW4h8KaEtJQ%2BDEkZkMVmx%2BB7j3zgUaECwOWaCXbS7wjJZ2PGq4HhqQH7RHp%2BSSrnTflFx6Md5NHniJZ7joXxpWWFVzsKwYY7UPQZ37UThrtbqbO1DYjrKrprRBTlHNltj1LLzNXy3llTT4d4yONjCcETK%2BCYlgu0%2FgAvq%2F1suZpag7nMeXfcvh4AdOAEGqas4MkB9d8XimZ3TnRqzKKIacCa%2BVFwro7qIP11%2Fc0GsuZPStinrrZOLkYNt3R%2FJPlkoVIfGEha2p5DVRdaj60R6mD%2BhCcknn44gks4Ae6XpQnBSpHJ4Cu16cKO1Gh5Q5wyjDaQlomXlnqhwDa2BKVfEDPrQ0y73cAVVar4WnT9U8uTPjJPIhwMRmV8HNY4IMGhSz76%2Byl%2BmbQE40ZhKf1mzLf9%2Ff%2FRoij05m9zPip%2B4ydeJBVNI7hiFdIVzZ0X%2BEx1j3GvqrVMxBvyri%2Bx4Nuktv4RTsug%2FApeD6xk0URecPDfw0lvY3hQvyzNTNIZ5AE8P2i8Vf0So5eUSPxUeOroyv2Bk7PcvaxTDqIg9%2ByHRsnfwFk%2BskVmgUAAA%3D%3D) to the analytics demo portal.
The two approaches require some time to get used to... and from what I have seen both are blazing fast. One advantage to the make-series and fir() approach is that it is 100% accurate while the HLL approach is heuristic and has some level of error. Another bonus is that it is really easy to configure the level of user engagement that would make the user eligible for the count.

```
let endtime=endofday(datetime(2017-03-01T00:00:00Z));
let window=60d;
let starttime=endtime-window;
let interval=1d;
let user_bins_to_analyze=28;
let moving_sum_filter=toscalar(range x from 1 to user_bins_to_analyze step 1 | extend v=1 | summarize makelist(v)); 
let min_activity=1;
customEvents
| where timestamp > starttime  
| where customDimensions["sourceapp"]=="ai-loganalyticsui-prod"
| where (name == "Checkout")  
| where user_AuthenticatedId <> ""
| make-series UserClicks=count() default=0 on timestamp in range(starttime, endtime-1s, interval) by user_AuthenticatedId
// create a new column containing a sliding sum. Passing 'false' as the last parameter to fir() prevents normalization of the calculation by the size of the window.
| extend RollingUserClicks=fir(UserClicks, moving_sum_filter, false)
| project User_AuthenticatedId=user_AuthenticatedId , RollingUserClicksByDay=zip(timestamp, RollingUserClicks)
| mvexpand RollingUserClicksByDay
| extend Timestamp=todatetime(RollingUserClicksByDay[0])
| extend RollingActiveUsersByDay=iff(toint(RollingUserClicksByDay[1]) >= min_activity, 1, 0)
| summarize sum(RollingActiveUsersByDay) by Timestamp
| where Timestamp > starttime + 28d
| render timechart
```